# SQL Server 2008 Append trigger end of table

Tags: sql-server-2008, append

I want to create a trigger running every day, on SQL Server 2008, that will append the results at the end of the existing table.

The query is the one below

```
select  
    count(distinct p.id), sid, GETDATE()
from 
    p
inner join 
    i1...
where 
    i1.sid in (25)
    and status = 3
    and p.id NOT IN (select  i2.patientConcerned
                     from Incident i2
                     where i2.serviceid = i1.serviceid
                       and i2.ServiceInterrupt != 0)
group by 
    serviceId
```

I can schedule to trigger (job) but I can't find how to append it at the end of an existing table.

Comment: In a relational database, a table doesn't have an *end* - it's just an unordered collection of rows. You just **insert** into a table - that's all - there's no *appending at the end*

Answer (score 0):

you cannot schedule a trigger to run on a certain time, becoz triggers are driven by events (after insert trigger, instead of insertion trigger, and etc). I think what you need is a job scheduled at the end of the day, this job will run your query which takes care of insertions.